# Twig for loop iteration

Tags: twig

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 49
            [thumb] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/OPC_Fabish3.0/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/banners/Productimage-278x355.jpg
            [rollover_thumb] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/OPC_Fabish3.0/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/banners/Productimage-278x355.jpg
            [name] => tulip lamp family
            [description] => Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, is the world’s thinnest tablet, measuring 8.6 mm thickness, running w..
            [price] => $241.99
            [special] => 
            [tax] => $199.99
            [rating] => 0
            [href] => http://192.168.0.101/user1/OPC_Fabish3.0/upload/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=49
            [model] => SAM1
        )
)
```

This is my `products` array in `PHP`.
In twig I am fetching the values using the following code:

```
{% for j in 0..(products|length) %}
    <a href="{{ products.j[href] }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

However I am not getting any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it is:

```
<a href="{{ products[j]['href'] }}"></a>
// or
<a href="{{ products[j].href }}"></a>
```

Or simplier:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <a href="{{ product.href }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: U do want to enquote the first `href` though. Now `twig` will consider it a(n undefined) variable

Comment: <a href="{{ products[j]['href'] }}"></a>
not working.

{% for product in products %}
    <a href="{{ product.href }}"></a>
{% endfor %}

will absolutely working but I want to tweak with array so I have to manually iterate through products array.

Comment: Then `products[j].href`

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Watch an [example](https://twigfiddle.com/3qxfgb). Don't forget you need to subtract one of your length, otherwise you'll reach an out of bounds on your array